Finding the negative solution to $\frac{1}{x^2-19x-40}+\frac{2}{x^2-19x-38}+\frac{1}{41-x^2+19x}=0$, if each denominator is an integer

Given that the denominator in each term in the following equation is an integer, find the negative solution to the following equation:
$$\frac{1}{x^2-19x-40}+\frac{2}{x^2-19x-38}+\frac{1}{41-x^2+19x}=0$$

I have already looked for the discriminant in $x^2-19x-40 = 0$, which is $521$, and can be changed to $529$, a square number which maximizes my chances of getting an integer, which leads to $x^2-19x-42 = 0$ and the solution so happens to be $-2$, which is the answer. But I feel like this is a very not-concrete solution, so I would like some hints on how to solve this purely algebraically.
I have also tried just common denominator-ing everything, but it just blows up into a quartic.

For simpler algebra, let the first term's denominator be
$$n = x^2 - 19x - 40$$
The other $2$ denominators are then
$$x^2 - 19x - 38 = n + 2, \;\; 41 - x^2 + 19x = -(x^2 - 19x - 40) + 1 = -n + 1$$
Using this in the provided equation gives
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{x^2-19x-40} + \frac{2}{x^2-19x-38} + \frac{1}{41 - x^2 + 19x} &= 0 \\
\frac{1}{n} + \frac{2}{n + 2} + \frac{1}{-n + 1} & = 0 \\
\frac{(n + 2)(-n + 1) + 2n(-n + 1) + n(n + 2)}{n(n + 2)(-n + 1)} & = 0 \\
\frac{(-n^2 -n + 2) + (-2n^2 + 2n) + (n^2 + 2n)}{n(n + 2)(-n + 1)} & = 0 \\
\frac{-2n^2 + 3n + 2}{n(n + 2)(-n + 1)} & = 0 \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
The numerator must be $0$, so the quadratic formula shows that
$$n = \frac{-3\pm\sqrt{3^2 - 4(-2)(2)}}{2(-2)} = \frac{-3\pm\sqrt{25}}{-4} = \frac{-3\pm 5}{-4} = -\frac{1}{2},\,2$$
As $n$ is stated to be an integer, then $n = 2$, as you've already suggested. Thus, we get from the first equation above that
$$x^2 - 19x - 40 = 2 \;\;\to\;\; x^2 - 19x - 42 = 0$$
Using the quadratic formula again results in
$$x = \frac{19\pm\sqrt{19^2-4(-42)}}{2} = \frac{19\pm\sqrt{529}}{2} = \frac{19\pm 23}{2} = -2,\,21$$
Since the question asks for the negative solution, this is $-2$, which you've stated is the official answer.

Thanks! I actually got halfway through your working out, but I don’t think I defined the top part properly so it all just crumbled apart


I have also tried just common denominator-ing everything, but it just blows up into a quartic.

I assume that the quartic you got was:
$$-2x^4 + 76 x^3 - 559 x^2 - 3097 x - 3318 = 0$$
Candidate integer solutions for $x$ are the factors of 3318, of which there are 16 (or 32 if you count ±).  Brute-forcing these gives $x = -2$ and $x = 21$ as solutions.  Dividing the quartic by the now-known factor $(x+2)(x-21) = x^2 - 19x - 42$ gives:
$$ -2 x^2 + 38 x + 79 = 0$$
From which the Quadratic formula gives the additional roots
$$x = \frac{19 \pm \sqrt{519}}{2}$$
And thus, the full solution set for the quartic is:
$$x \in \{-2, 21, \frac{19 + \sqrt{519}}{2}, \frac{19 - \sqrt{519}}{2}\} $$
To make sure that these solutions satisfy the original equation, evaluate the denominators $(x^2-19x-40, x^2-19x-38, 41-x^2+19x)$ to ensure that none are zero:

$x = -2 : (2, 4, -1)$
$x = 21 : (2, 4, -1)$
$x = \frac{19 + \sqrt{519}}{2} : (-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{3}{2})$
$x = \frac{19 - \sqrt{519}}{2} : (-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{3}{2})$

So no divide-by-zero errors here.  However, only one of the four solutions satisfies the problem's constraint of $x < 0$ and all three denominators being integers:
$$\boxed{x = -2}$$
